# assign a function to a variable dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-schedule

i want to get information from several machines via soap api at specefic time ( every 5 min )
so i am using node-schedule and i want to make several schedules depending on each machine in my database.
i am using this code:

```
//fetch machines configrations
function readMachinesConfig() {
  return pool.query("SELECT * FROM machines").then(res => {
    const machines = {};
    res.rows.map(machine => {
      let machine_line = machine.machine_name + "/" + machine.machine_line;
      machines[machine_line] = { url: machine.url, scantime: machine.scantime };
    });
    return machines;
  });
}

readMachinesConfig().then(res => {
  Object.keys(res).map((machine, index) => {
    let scantime = "*/" + res[machine].scantime + " * * * *";
    //***HOW to set variable name dynamically*** 
    jobs[index] = schedule.scheduleJob(scantime, function() {
      console.log(scantime);
    });
  });
  return jobs;
});
```

so i want to set the variable name that hold the schedule function dynamically so i can reschedule it or cancel it later.

> jobs[index] = schedule.scheduleJob(scantime, function() {
>         console.log(scantime);
>       });

how can i do that?

Comment: Can you provide a working example? This code is out of context. Where are these functions called? Where is jobs described?

Comment: jobs is only an empty array which i declare the functions to it ( for now ) but i want a way to put the dynamically generated variable instead of it. ( the names are in the database)

Comment: the function is called after the machine configuration is entered in another file ( to start calling the api for it )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use cron-job-maanger to modify jobs

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron-job-manager